# my app's joysticks don't work in android studio, they don't appear

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I have a problem with the code of my joysticks, it displays "Class referenced in the layout file, `io.github.controlwear.virtual.joystick.android.JoystickView`, was not found in the project or the libraries ' .
I am new in programming, your help will be beneficial to me.

```
here is the code for the left, same problem for the right 


<io.github.controlwear.virtual.joystick.android.JoystickView
        android:id="@+id/joystickViewLeft"
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="26dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:JV_backgroundColor="#20000000"
        app:JV_borderWidth="4dp"
        app:JV_buttonColor="#ffcc00"
        app:JV_buttonSizeRatio="35%"
        app:JV_fixedCenter="false"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/joystickViewRight"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.032"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

Comment: Did you import the associated library as a dependency in your build.gradle file?

Comment: @Tenfour04 yes I imported the library, no change

Answer (score 0):

First import the associated library in build.gradle file.Then rebuild the project.(Or just press sync now button)

Comment: so far the problem persists